# How to input a list in list in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I want to create a list in Python. That list contains N lists. Here, N == int(input()).

Say, I want to create a list which again contains N list. N is the number of people and that sub_list will contain the people's name and age.

I want to keep the data in this format: Sub_list = [name, age]. I want this sub list to be a part of the main list. So, basically it should look like this: main_list = [[name, age], [name, age], [name, age]...N]. But, I want to input() the name and age and also keep the [name, age] as a sub-list being a part of main list. How do I do that?

I'm really sorry for asking such a silly question. I'm new to Python and programming as a whole. I tried to solve this problem on my own for while. But couldn't. So, I've decided to share this silly problem in StackOverflow. Sorry for inconvenience :'(

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on his own. A good way to show this effort is to include a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Check the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) you were *supposed* to finish before posting, especially [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Why would you keep name and age in a list rather than a dictionary? Lists should generally be for uniform collections.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You have to first share a snippet of code to show what you have tried.

Comment: There are many examples on line and on this site that illustrate how to input a series of data.  There are many examples of putting a series of data into a list.  How did *none* of those get you to a point where you code write any code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this could help you out

```
list=[]
for i in range(0,N):
   name=raw_input('Enter Name:')
   age=raw_input('Enter Age:')
   list.append([name,int(age)])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ch = int(input("Enter count"))
cur = 0
details = []

while (cur < ch):
    cur += 1
    name = input("Enter name")
    age = int(input("Enterage"))
    details.append([name, age])

print(details)
```

However this is not a good approach to store organized data. Trying doing this in dictionary